# How to loop through a List of Objects

Tags: java, list, loops

I have a class called `Group`. Inside `Group` there is a list the contains objects of type `Customer`, like so:

```
Group.java:

private List<Customers> customers;

public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
   return customers;
}
```

Then, like above, the class `Customer` has list that contains object of type `EmailAddress`, like so:

```
Customer.java:

private List<EmailAddress> emailAddresses;

public List<EmailAddress> getEmailAddress() {
   return emailAddresses;
}
```

I want to be able to put this list of email addresses into my own list that I can then manipulate how I want. So in my `Main.java` I have:

```
Main.java:

List<Customer> customerList = group.getCustomers(); //group is the object to get <Customer> List

for (int i=0; i<customerList.size(); i++) {

List<EmailAddress> emails = customerList.get(i).getEmailAddresses();

}
```

Will I then, outside of this for loop, have a List of all the emails of the customers that I can use? Is this the correct way to populate a list that I can then utilize and pull data from outside of this loop? Outside of the loop I want to be able to look at different parts of the list like:

```
emails.get(3);
```

or

```
emails.get(7);
```

at my own discretion.

Comment: Warning: problems *may* arise when you return a bare list. If the list is *mutable*, then the caller may change your list, and this is reflected within your `Group` and `Customer` instances. This is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the list outside the for cycle

```
List<EmailAddress> emails = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0; i<customerList.size(); i++) {
    emails.add(customerList.get(i).getEmailAddresses());
}
```

Comment: will I then have the full list outside of the for loop?

Comment: Yes, in the method that the list is initialized. If you need it outside the method you should declare it as a field of the class or return it in the method.

Comment: Should be `addAll(customerList.get(i).getEmailAddresses())`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Customer> customerList = group.getCustomers();
List<EmailAddress> finalEmailAddressList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Customer : customerList) {
    if (customer != null) {
        finalEmailAddressList.add(customer.getEmailAddresses());
    }
}
```

This should give you a list of all email addresses in the end. You can also use the `addAll` method to add a collection to a collection (at specific indexes also), in this case, a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in functional style:

```java
List<EmailAddress> emails = costumerList.stream()
    .map(Customer::getEmailAddresses)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The most interesting part here is the [flatMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) method which does two things:

- It *maps* a `List<EmailAddress>` to a `Stream<EmailAddress>` by using [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) of the [Collection.stream()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#stream()) method
- It *flattens* the result so that the result is of type `Stream<EmailAdress>`
  Consequently, the result of the `collect()` method will be of type `List<EmailAdress>`

In contrast, if the `flatMap()` line was omitted, the result would be of type `List<List<EmailAddress>>`.
Similarly, if the [map()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) method was used instead of `flatmap()`, the result would be of type `List<Stream<EmailAddress>>`

Comment: Should be `.map(Customer::getEmailAddresses).flatMap(Collection::stream)`

Comment: @knitti Thanks! Updated, it is easier when you have an IDE at hand

Answer (score 0):

If access to data is required from an outer scope, the data has to exist in the outer scope. Therefore, you need to declare it in the outer scope of the loop:

```
List<Customer> customerList = group.getCustomers();
List<EmailAddress> emails = new ArrayList<>(customerList.size());
for (Customer customer : customerList) {
    emails.addAll(customer.getEmailAddresses();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with streams:

```
List<Group> groupList = ...
List<EmailAddress> address = groupList
  .stream()
  .flatMap(g -> g.getCustomers().stream())
  .flatMap(c -> c.getEmailAddresses().stream())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```